# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager items shifting positions randomly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

using a gridlayout in RecyclerView and I observed that whenever I get around 4-5 items on screen the items would change positions, I've implemented an onclick so that it would go into another page

```
public interface ItemClickCallback {
    void onItemClick(int p, String id);

}

public void setItemClickCallback(final ItemClickCallback itemClickCallback) {
    this.itemClickCallback = itemClickCallback;

}

public nAdapter(RealmResults<Nitem> listData, Context c) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.listData = listData;
}


@Override
public nHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.n_item, parent, false);
    return new nHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(nAdapter.nHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Nitem item = (Nitem) listData.get(position);
    holder.title.setPadding(7,7,7,7);
    if(holder.title.toString().isEmpty()) {
        holder.title.setText(item.getNotes());
    }
        holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickCallback.onItemClick(position,item.getId());
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Views in RecyclerView are reused.

It means that while you are scrolling up or down the list, rather than creating completely new view, previously created views are reused.

Implicitly, it enforces you to update view content again and again (not only when you expecting it is empty).

Probably you have a problem with misplaced titles? It occurs because you are setting title only, when it is empty (what is true only for few not-yet-cached views).

Just remove `if` condition and you should be fine.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(nAdapter.nHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Nitem item = (Nitem) listData.get(position);
    holder.title.setPadding(7,7,7,7);
    // Always update view's data.
    holder.title.setText(item.getNotes());
    holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickCallback.onItemClick(position,item.getId());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: removed the if statement and nothing changed,does it help that I use realm as its database